# How can i delete instant app support on my project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-3.1-honeycomb

I'm new at Android Development. I see a new feature on Android Studio after update. There was a Instant App Support on there. I thought It is a instant view and i clicked it and now i know what it is. How can i remove that support on my project?

Android Studio 3.1.3

Comment: dont use it .. whats wrong in that ?

Comment: drop back to a previous version where that feature wasn't there lol

Comment: I have no wrong for now. I just wanted to learn that. I tried to connect Firebase Authentication and there was a two thing. "App" and "Instant App". I do not wanted to take an error from after. That's why i established a new project and started again. But i want to learn how can i remove that from my project

Comment: You mean when you created a new project, and you checked that box for Instant App support? No, there's no "one-click" way to remove it from your project. You'll either have to 1. move your code around into the application module, rework the dependencies, 2. create a new project, 3. don't setup an assetlinks.json, but continue to work the project structure of an IA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you can delete the feature. Instead, you can disable it.

[Opt in or out of Instant Apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7240211?hl=en):

1. On your device, open the Settings app Settings.
2. Go to Google then Instant Apps.
3. Under "Instant Apps account," select which account to opt in our out of. To opt out for all accounts, tap None.
   Sometimes there's a slide widget that's switched On. Go and turn it off.

Comment: This setting is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

This post is adding to @noogui's post. There is another way if you don't see "Instant Apps" as soon as you click Google in Settings.

1. Click Settings
2. Click Google
3. Click Account Services
4. Click Google Play Instant
5. Turn the toggle bar OFF

-Hope that helps anyone in the future!

God bless and stay safe!